# In page navigation works in Firefox but not in IE or Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-11

I am currently fixing a Drupal 7 site that has to work in all current browsers. I am having an issue with in page navigation. The links work fine in Firefox but are not working in Internet Explorer 11 or Chrome.

A test version of the site can be found at http://www.tztesting.com

An example of a url not working is on the page, at a Learn More link on the main banner graphic as http://www.tztesting.com/ourservices#servicesteps

Further down the page is a block with a fair bit of content. Above the block is the following

```
<div class="top_pad"><a name="servicesteps"></a>here</div>
```

The class top_pad is defined in css as follows

```
.top_pad {
    font-size:x-large;
    min-height:80px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

I have tried removing the anchor from the target and just making this an id, as I believe anchors with name is old and is no longer supported.

I know this sort of thing could well be done in JQuery or JavaScript but that is not an option as the client wishes to maintain the ability to edit content through the Drupal CMS and it is not possible to have them editing templates.

I would appreciate it if someone could show me the error of my ways so I can get these in page links working in IE and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

What you have described should work fine.  You are right that you shouldn't use name for fragment anchors, but I doubt any browser has removed that functionality because it would break the old web.  It certainly still works in Chrome.

The reason your link is not navigating the page as you expect is because you have some sort of click event handler that is throwing an error.  So the issue appears to be specific to some script you are running on this page, rather than how fragment anchors work.

Answer (score 0):

I went deep into the code and found out the issue is not your fault. Anchors with names are still fully supported and that alone should work. However bootstrap and jQuery are using a fancy animation to scroll you towards the bottom instead of a browser's default behavior which is to jump there.

The problem is that this animation was not implemented correctly, and because there is either a bug in the jQuery, Bootstrap, Drupal or (most likely) a bug in the communication between all of them, an error will be thrown in the console every time you click any anchor link on your site.

The reason this does happen in firefox and internet explorer is because in the special Boostrap verison that Drupal uses, there is a bug that makes this behavior not work in firefox and internet explorer (and probably other browsers). This causes the browser to just use the normal behavior, where there is no bug, and it jumps normally as it should.

I recommend you take this to Drupal and report this as a bug. Seeing as Drupal 7 is already 5 years old, they will most likely tell you to just use Drupal 8 and stop complaining. However I can give you a way to fix the bug. Replace the default loading of jquery with a link that loads your local version of jquery having this code in it: http://pastebin.com/VHc2RC3P

If you can't or don't want to do this you could probably write some javascript code to do what the browser does by default and just override what the libraries are trying to do.

Comment: I agree that a switch to Drupal 8 would probably be the best solution. Unfortunately the client is insisting on staying with Drupal 7 and all its bugs. This modified jQuery solution does get the in page navigation working in the different browsers. There is a javascript console error though `TypeError: e.createDocumentFragment is not a function`. I have also noticed that the fadeIn and fadeOut functions do not work with this modified version of jQuery. Is there an easy solution to this error?

Comment: I've created a new version of the jQuery here: http://pastebin.com/vcAfL1SH
this should fix the error you get in theory, which should in turn fix the fadeIn and fadeOut. I don't know if it's actually related to the fadeIn and fadeOut but this change should only fix anything and not break anything else unlike the last change i made.

Comment: Do you happen to have the original jQuery file for me? The one that was used before I posted the first corrected version. If I look at that I might be able to fix it.

Comment: The site is a Drupal 7 site that uses jQuery 1.4.4 as a base version of jQuery. It then uses a module, jQuery update, that does the following "Update jQuery and jQuery UI to a more recent version". The module allows me to update to jQuery 1.10 and it gets a minified version from the jQuery CDN. If you would like to see the version of jQuery being used it can be seen at [link](http://www.tztesting.com). If you could look at the jQuery errors affecting this site I would be most appreciative as I need to get this site into production urgently.

Comment: Note it is possible for me to switch the jquery update module to use an uncompressed version of jQuery instead of the minified version if that helps in debugging

Comment: i've noticed that you aren't using my modified version of the jQuery which is most likely causing the issue. Also instead of using the version i last sent this version should work better: http://pastebin.com/4VyWHRZ7.
If you can't really replace the jQuery with my jQuery running this code snippet after jQuery has loaded should do the job as well. http://pastebin.com/e9tBAeYH

Comment: I took the modified version of jquery out because other Drupal functions, mostly related to the admin functionality broke. I will try the snippet you have just sent and see how I go with that